# Access Json arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

(It's actually for an assignment)

Hi,
For hours I tried to solve my problem, I found some solutions, but it wasn't really what I wanted, and from my code I'm always hitting the same wall.
thank you.

So I have a JSON file and a javascript file :

In my JSON file I have simple array of list of URL

```
    {
        "myUrlDatabase":[
            "https://www.francebleu.fr/emissions/ca-va-dans-le-bon-sens-en-poitou/poitou/quel-est-l-impact-du-changement-climatique-sur-les-migrations-d-oiseaux-marins",
            "https://www.terrafemina.com/article/environnement-pourquoi-2021-est-une-annee-cruciale-pour-agir_a357981/1",
            "https://www.franceinter.fr/monde/rechauffement-climatique-2020-est-l-annee-la-plus-chaude-jamais-enregistree-en-europe",
//more url
        ]}
```

I would like to access it in my javascript file, from what I have seen, I should use the fetch function, I followed a code on internet

```
fetch('/Data/url.json').then(function (response){
  return response.json();
}).then(function (obj){
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Indeed it print the file. but how can I make a var of the array ?

I would like later to use it in a random function

```
Math.randon() * {JSONFILE.length}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` delivers a `Promise`, so you have to use a (callback) lambda to use its result. Here's an example for that, mocking your random function for the keys of the result.

```js
const postFetch = data => {
  if (!data.error) {
    const allKeys = Object.keys(data.results);
    const someKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * allKeys.length);
    console.log(`A pseudo random result => ${allKeys[someKey]}: ${
      data.results[allKeys[someKey]]}`);
    console.log(`The original json: ${JSON.stringify(data.results)}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`an error occured: ${data.message}`);
  }
}

fetch("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=53.22179255&lng=6.5582453664798")
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(postFetch)
  //    ^ continue with the resulting object within your own function
  .catch(error => ({
    error: true,
    url,
    message: error.message
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access nested properties within the parsed JSON simply as fields within the `obj` parameter. The field which you want to access is `myUrlDatabase`.

```
var array = obj.myUrlDatabase
console.log(array.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JSON.parse()` method to transform json into a JavaScript data structure.
Similar to your example:

```js
// your response
const jsonInfo = "{ \"propArr\": [ \"string1\", \"string2\", \"string3\" ] }"
// use the parse() method
const getTheArray = JSON.parse(jsonInfo).propArr;

console.log(getTheArray);
```

Or if your data is already an object just do `const whatIWant = receivedData.theArrayIWant` and you'll have the `whatIWant` array.